# PHP and access to string like to assoc array

Tags: php, string

Is that logical behavior?

```
$str = 'string';  
$res = $str['some_key'];  
echo (int)isset($str['some_key']); // 1  
echo $res; // 's'
```

It's a bug or unclear feature?

Comment: `(int)isset($str['some_key'])` echoes `1` because `isset` returns `true`.

Comment: Let me put it like this: "It's only logical." :)

Comment: Fixed in [5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/migration54.incompatible.php)

Answer (score 10):

It is a "feature". When using `$string[$index]`, `$index` is treated as integer, so `'some_key'` is converted to `0`. That's also why you get `'s'` (first letter of `$str`) in `$res`.

```
$str = 'Lorem';
var_dump($str['key']); // L, because (int)'key' is 0
var_dump($str['0key']); // L
var_dump($str['1key']); // o, because (int)'1key' is 1
var_dump($str['2key']); // r
var_dump($str['3key']); // e, because (int)'3key' is 3
var_dump($str['4key']); // m
var_dump($str['5key']); // Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 5 in sandbox\index.php on line 20
```

Answer (score 3):

[Accessing strings like arrays is a feature.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)
Strings only have *numeric offsets*, any "key" you use is cast to an int.
[Non-numeric strings cast to the int `0`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)
Hence `$str["foo"]` is equivalent to `$str[0]`.

So there is *a logic*, whether you want to call it *logical* or not is up to you.
But if you're accessing strings with string keys, something's wrong with your code anyway. ;-)